# Weird math question in ACT prep

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I do not even know where to begin here. I was taking one of the ACT prep quizzes for school the other day and came across a question that I cannot even begin to understand.

For all $a$ and $b$ such that $-1 < a < 0$ and $0 < b < 1$, which of the following had the LARGEST value?

The possible answers were:
$$\begin{align*}
&b\\
&b^2\\
&a + b\\
&a^2 + b^2\\
&b - a
\end{align*}$$
How in the world is this question even possible to answer? How can you even begin to solve this question in order to find an answer? Just in case, I will be looking for the question or similar questions when I take the next prep quiz today.

Comment: At least three times----once in the subject line and twice within the question itself----you emit exclamations about how weird you think this question is.  You're out of touch if you think that.  It's pretty routine stuff.  I'm not sure what they typically put at the ACT, but this is not outside the mainstream as elementary math questions go.

Answer (score 10):

Since $0<b<1$, we know that $0<b^2<b$, so we can rule out $b^2$. Moreover, $a<0$, so $a+b<b$, and we can rule out $a+b$. On the other hand, for the same reason we must have $b-a>b$, so our choices boil down to $b-a$ and $a^2+b^2$. Finally, we already know that $b-b^2>0$, and $a+a^2=a^2-|a|<0$ for the same reason, so

$$(b-a)-\left(a^2+b^2\right)=\left(b-b^2\right)-\left(a+a^2\right)>0\;,$$

and $b-a$ is the winner.

Comment: So, it is looking for the largest number we could get by combining the unknowns? That seems a bit odd, as it doesn't have any practical purposes that I can think of. Why is this stuff in the ACT prep? Isn't the ACT just a way of measuring your skills and intelligence?

Comment: @Justin: It’s asking you to compare the values of the five functions, given that $a$ and $b$ are in the specified intervals. Presumably it’s designed to test your understanding of the certain aspects of the behavior of real numbers and your problem-solving skills.

Comment: Testing intelligence is testing reasoning, and this is a reasoning problem. You could have just done this problem by selecting $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$ since it is implicit in a multiple choice problem that one of the answers is right. :)

Comment: Part of this answer is needlessly complicated.  When comparing $b-a$  and $b^2+a^2$, observe that (as noted above) $b^2<b$, and for the same reason, $a^2<-a$, so $b-a>b^2+a^2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you cheat.

Comment: @Michael: Your argument is essentially identical to the one that I gave.

Comment: Fixed. ${{{{}}}}$

Comment: @Michael: Ditto. :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : I think I expressed it in a simpler way.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Your answer is definitely simpler, since we don't have a lot of signs to worry about in the analysis. Still, it is basically the same proof.

Comment: @vonbrand One of the ways that I was good at both standardized tests and math contest problems was that I could figure out "cheats" like that. Certainly, in this problem, it helps to take specific $a,b$ to "check" your answer at minimum, but here, due to the nature of the problem (and specifically, the lack of an "unable to determine with infomation given" option) picking specific values is actually enough.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, it wasn't meant as a derogatory comment, quite the contrary.

Comment: @vonbrand Oh, no, I took it as a compliment. Although in general if you use a word like "cheat" humorously on a forum where lots of people have different English language, it is possibly best bet to include the dreaded smiley or quote the term. I am well versed in irony, but a lot of other folks here are either not native English speakers or are excessively literal-minded. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a test taking skill question than anything else. The fastest way to figure out the answer would be to plug in numbers, say $a = -{1 \over 2}$ and $b = {1 \over 2}$. Your 5 choices become ${1 \over 2}, {1 \over 4}, 0, {1 \over 2},$ and $1$. So choose e) and move on to the next problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What you have to do is notice that $a$ is negative, while $b$ is positive and the fact that they are both fractions, what does this tell you when you look at the different choices? Try to put some bounds on the expressions.

Comment: Well, logically thinking, b would be the largest. If b were less than 1 the square of b would be less than b itself. I do not know if that is the answer though because the question is stated in a very confusing way. Is it really just looking for the largest of the two unknown numbers?

Comment: Why do you think that a and b are necessarily fractions? "Fraction" does not mean an (absolute) value of less than 1.

Comment: @ypercube: that might be misleading. The point was that if you square one of the numbers, it's less than what it was originally so, $b^2 \le b$

Comment: What might be misleading? That you say "fraction" while you probably mean "proper fraction"?

Comment: @ypercube: yes!